# Problem related to NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

today, I encountered a problem with `NSURLConnection`. I want to download the contents of the URL `http://api.wunderground.com/api/fs3a45dsa345/geolookup/q/34.532900,-122.345.json`. If I simply paste the URL into Safari, I get the correct response. However, if I do the same thing with `NSURLConnection`, I get a "not found" response. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"same url as above"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL];
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                         startImmediately:YES];
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're escaping any special characters in the URL string by sending it a `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` message, for example:

```
NSString *s = [@"some url string" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTFStringEncoding];
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
```

**EDIT**

It turns out the web service request is failing because the **User-Agent** header doesn't get set by default. To set it, use an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest` rather than `NSURLRequest` to create the request, as shown below:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[myRequest setValue:@"My App" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Doesn't work either (the method doesn't alter the string). I used other url encoding techniques, too, but none of them worked.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it now works! May I ask how you found this out?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the delegate code?  For async `NSURLConnection` there needs to be a `delegate` method to receive the returned data.  Other options include `sendSynchronousRequest`: or if it must be async wrapping `sendSynchronousRequest` in a `GCD block`.

Comment: It's implemented, but I left it out because it is working correctly (the website returns an HTML page that says "not found").